# What is the easiest way to implement CRUD with GWTP (and Objectify for the persistence)?

Tags: crud, objectify, gwt-platform

Is there a library, an eclipse plugin to generate code, or a recommended design pattern ? Any example with GWTP ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into `RequestFactory`: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

Also a sample code with `GWTP`, `GAE`, `Objectify` and `RequestFactory`: http://code.google.com/p/gwtgae2011/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think the best way is here : http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

May this is not exactly what you are looking for but this may be help ful to you.
Google [gwtp](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted) example.

Comment: I am already using GWTP, I have seen SPRING ROO that is powerfull to create the CRUD backend. But I do not have heard about ROO and GWTP together...so I would like to avoid the maximum boilerplate code with another alternative...